# Join two big tables on multiple columns in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two tables:

1. Transactions with around 300,000 rows, and following fields:

   - TransactionID
   - ClientID
   - Q
   - Y
   - Type
2. Prices with around 10,000 rows, and following fields:

   - ClientID
   - Q
   - Y
   - Type
   - Price

I try to join them using 4 fields: `ClientID, Q, Y, Type`, but I get 2GB error all the time, saying result table is too big. The thing is the result should be 300,000 rows, so my guess is Access does it in some stupid way, creating cartesian product first and throwing an error. Funny thing is, that if I use just `ClientID` to join it works fine and gives couple millions of rows.

Can somebody help me to find the right way out? Maybe I just need to learn how joins are executed behind the scenes, but I haven't found anything meaningful so far.

I consider adding *hash* column that would have 4 columns concatenated in both tables and use it to join, but it's so ugly solution I just cringe.

My current SQL is like

```
SELECT TransactionID, Price 
FROM Transactions 
INNER JOIN Prices
   ON Transactions.ClientID = Prices.ClientID 
  AND Transactions.Q = Prices.Q 
  AND Transactions.Y = Prices.Y 
  AND Transactions.Type = Prices.Type
```

Comment: What is the current size of database with just those two tables?

Comment: Did you compact the db before joining ?

Comment: do you have proper index on clientId ?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I don't, but the ultimate goal is to have those tables generated dynamically, so I don't think it's a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a derived table to force a different query execution:

```
SELECT TransactionID, Price FROM 
(SELECT TransactionID, Price, Transactions.Q as TransQ, Prices.Q as PricesQ,
Transactions.Y as TransY, Prices.Y as PricesY, Transactions.Type as
TransType, Prices.Type as PricesType
FROM Transactions INNER JOIN Prices
ON Transactions.ClientID = Prices.ClientID) AS Step1
WHERE TransQ = PricesQ AND TransY = PricesY
AND TransType = PricesType
```

Comment: The idea is neat, but apparently Access wants to be smarter than me, and still throws errors. However yours and @Parfait ideas resulted in workaround I'm gonna use. I'll put results of join on just ClientID in temporary database, then select just those with matching Q, Y, and Type.

Comment: @brainac ... curious, what was the result of linking data table .accdb file with query app .accdb file where you run original query in latter file on linked tables of former?

Comment: @Parfait not sure if I understand your question, but ultimately I put resulting table of around 11 million records in temporary DB, just using [;database=] in query, then I removed rows with not matching Qs, Ys, and Types. Remaining 300k rows were easily joined with the table that was meant to store the results. It took something like 3 hours, and 350MB, but since it's one time exercise, I'm fine with this. Next time I'll be doing it for just one month, not 2 years of data, so it will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Access 2016 specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2016-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c), the size limit is defined as:

> 2 gigabytes, minus the space needed for system objects.

Virtual tables in processing this query may be the issue.  To display a `SELECT` statement results in a query window, data needs to be stored temporarily in a system object. If original file is already large, it will be even larger with the join (i.e., copy) of same tables in a `JOIN` query.

As recommended by the same above specs, consider migrating *Prices* into a different .accdb/.mdb file and query using linked tables (Access to Access). And if you retain same table names, original query would not need to change! Alternatively, query externally such as below. This way you divorce processing temporary table size from storage size to fit 2GB quota.

```
SELECT t.TransactionID, Price 
FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN [C:\Path\To\Other\Database.accdb].[Prices] p
   ON t.ClientID = p.ClientID 
  AND t.Q = p.Q 
  AND t.Y = p.Y 
  AND t.Type = p.Type
```

Even still, store both tables in different file(s) and use a different, data-less Access app to run the query. In fact, this is ideally the split architecture recommended with Access development where storage (BackEnd) with tables is separated from application (FrontEnd) with queries/forms/reports/macros/modules.

[image: Split Architecture]